# How to create a typeable Pinia base store with the correct Typescript types?

Tags: typescript, pinia

I'm currently trying to develop a typeable Pinia base store which can then be used to create stores with the same structure but with different model types, but I got stuck on defining the correct Typescript types. Especially with the correct definition of the getters.

This is my current (working) approach:

```js
import { type _GettersTree, defineStore } from 'pinia';
import type { ICustomDataTableHeader } from '@/components/DataTableActions.vue';
import type { UnwrapRefSimple } from '@vue/reactivity';
import { FetchError } from 'ofetch';

export interface IModel {
  id: number;
}

export interface IDefaultStoreState<CustomType extends IModel> {
  items: CustomType[];
  item: CustomType;
  headers: ICustomDataTableHeader[];
  schema: any;
  schemaGroups?: string[][];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: FetchError | null;
}


export interface IDefaultStoreActions<CustomType extends IModel> {
  add(values: CustomType): Promise<void>;
  delete(id: number): Promise<void>;
  fetchAll(): Promise<void>;
  fetchOne(id: number): Promise<void>;
  patch(id: number, values: CustomType): Promise<void>;
}

export interface IDefaultStoreGetters<CustomType extends IModel> {
  getAll: (state: IDefaultStoreState<CustomType>) => CustomType[]
  getById: (state: IDefaultStoreState<CustomType>) => (id: number) => CustomType | undefined;
}

export function createDefaultStore<CustomType extends IModel>(storeId: string, apiUrl: string, defaults?: Partial<IDefaultStoreState<CustomType>>) {
  return defineStore<typeof storeId, IDefaultStoreState<CustomType>, _GettersTree<IDefaultStoreState<CustomType>>, IDefaultStoreActions<CustomType>>(storeId, {
    state: (): IDefaultStoreState<CustomType> => ({
      items: defaults?.items ?? [],
      item: defaults?.item ?? {} as CustomType,
      headers: defaults?.headers ?? [],
      schema: defaults?.schema ?? {},
      schemaGroups: defaults?.schemaGroups ?? [],
      isLoading: defaults?.isLoading ?? false,
      error: defaults?.error ?? null,
    }),
    actions: {
      async add(values: CustomType) {
        this.isLoading = true
        try {
          this.error = null
          const { data, error } = await useLaravelFetch<CustomType>(apiUrl, {
            method: 'post' as any,
            body: values
          })
          if (error.value) {
            this.error = error.value
          } else if (data.value) {
            this.items.push(data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType>)
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error as FetchError
        } finally {
          this.isLoading = false
        }
      },
      async delete(id: number) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        try {
          this.error = null;
          await useLaravelFetch(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, {
            method: 'delete',
          });
          this.items.splice(this.items.findIndex(c => c.id === id), 1);
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error as FetchError;
        } finally {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      },
      async fetchAll() {
        this.isLoading = true
        try {
          this.error = null
          const { data, error } = await useLaravelFetch<CustomType[]>(apiUrl, { lazy: true })
          watch([data, error], () => {
            if (error.value) {
              this.error = error.value
            } else if (data.value) {
              this.items = data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType[]>
            }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error as FetchError
        } finally {
          this.isLoading = false
        }
      },
      async fetchOne(id: number) {
        this.isLoading = true
        try {
          this.error = null
          const { data, error } = await useLaravelFetch<CustomType>(`${apiUrl}/${id}`)
          if (error.value) {
            this.error = error.value
          } else if (data.value) {
            const intCurrentIndex: number = this.items.findIndex(c => c.id === id)
            if (intCurrentIndex === -1) {
              this.items.push(data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType>)
            } else {
              this.items.splice(intCurrentIndex, 1, data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType>)
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error as FetchError
        } finally {
          this.isLoading = false
        }
      },
      async patch(id: number, values: CustomType) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        try {
          this.error = null;
          const { data, error } = await useLaravelFetch<CustomType>(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, {
            method: 'patch' as any,
            body: values,
          });
          if (error.value) {
            this.error = error.value;
          } else if (data.value) {
            const intCurrentIndex: number = this.items.findIndex(c => c.id === id);
            if (intCurrentIndex === -1) {
              this.items.push(data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType>);
            } else {
              this.items.splice(intCurrentIndex, 1, data.value as UnwrapRefSimple<CustomType>);
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error as FetchError;
        } finally {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      },
    },
    getters: {
      getAll: (state) => state.items,
      getById: (state) => {
        return (id: number) => state.items.find((item) => item.id === id);
      },
    },
  });
}
```

So with this function I am able to create pinia stores like this:

```js
export interface ICustomModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  company: string;
  is_active?: boolean;
}

export const useCustomStore = createDefaultStore<ICustomModel>('custom-store', '/api/custom');
```

Although this works for now, I would still like to define the getters correctly. At the moment, the getters are not recognised by the IDE at all. Instead, I end up in the Pinia documentation when I click on a getter:

```js
export declare type _StoreWithGetters<G> = {
    readonly [k in keyof G]: G[k] extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : UnwrapRef<G[k]>;
```

All attempts to replace `_GettersTree` with something of my own have failed so far. The problem obviously arises, as far as I have been able to narrow it down so far, from the typing with a specific interface. This is why, for example, `method: 'post' as any` is defined as `any`, because Typescript has difficulties determining the correct type here. Unfortunately, I'm at the end of my tether and am open to suggestions.